# Redux Provider not passing down Props/State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've created a React App using create-react-app and added Redux to it. After adding `<Provider store={store} />` only the component that I pass as the argument (the main component) on `connect`is receiving the props/state.
Why do the nested components not receive them?

I will not paste the code here because I don't know what is causing the problem. Instead, here is the link to the entire App: https://github.com/KadoBOT/Box.es

Comment: bacause you are not `connect`ing them to the store

Comment: The `connect` is there: const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === 'template' ? TemplatePage : MainPage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are `connect`ing only `MainPage or TemplatePage` component, depends on condition. But you dont push props down. Here are couple ways how you can get it in your child components

1. [**`React.cloneElement`**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)
2. using `connect` **>** `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent)`
3. You can pass it explicitly from `MainPage or TemplatePage` component 
   `<ItemView {...this.props}/> ... <ItemSidebar {...this.props}/>`

Thanks

Comment: Though there was a way to pass them down automactly without having to specify on every child component or through connect.

Thanks, mate.